# udev rule parameter for systemd template

Tags: systemd, udev

Background: I want to start a log script when my usb-uart device connects.

My `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1366", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1015", ATTRS{serial}=="000621000000", SYMLINK+="ttymkw", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}+="offnet-uart-log@$env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}.service"
```

My `~/.config/systemd/user/offnet-uart-log@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start log of UART

[Service]
ExecStart=sh -c "echo %I >> /tmp/systemd.test"
```

This does not give me the expected value of `ID_SERIAL_SHORT`. Instead, I get a long sys path:

```
sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.7/3-1.7.2/3-1.7.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
```

When I try to get the properties for this path (I need to remove the leading `sys`), I can see `ID_SERIAL_SHORT`:

```
$ udevadm info --query=property --path /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.7/3-1.7.2/3-1.7.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0DEVPATH=//devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.7/3-1.7.2/3-1.7.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
DEVNAME=/dev/ttyACM0
MAJOR=166
MINOR=0
SUBSYSTEM=tty
USEC_INITIALIZED=1633350773062
SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS=offnet-uart-log@.service
ID_BUS=usb
ID_VENDOR_ID=1366
ID_MODEL_ID=1015
ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Serial bus controller
ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=USB controller
ID_PCI_INTERFACE_FROM_DATABASE=XHCI
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=SEGGER
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=DSL6340 USB 3.1 Controller [Alpine Ridge]
ID_VENDOR=SEGGER
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SEGGER
ID_MODEL=J-Link
ID_MODEL_ENC=J-Link
ID_REVISION=0100
ID_SERIAL=SEGGER_J-Link_000621000000
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=000621000000                 ### <--- here
ID_TYPE=generic
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:020201:0a0000:ffffff:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_USB_DRIVER=cdc_acm
ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Miscellaneous Device
ID_USB_PROTOCOL_FROM_DATABASE=Interface Association
ID_PATH=pci-0000:39:00.0-usb-0:1.7.2:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_39_00_0-usb-0_1_7_2_1_0
ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
DEVLINKS=/dev/ttymkw /dev/serial/by-id/usb-SEGGER_J-Link_000621000000-if00 /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:39:00.0-usb-0:1.7.2:1.0
TAGS=:systemd:
```

`$env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}` in my udev rule does not seem to be replaced with the value of the property.

The man page for udev says that the `$env{key}` substitution is only available for the NAME, SYMLINK, PROGRAM, OWNER, GROUP, MODE, SECLABEL, and RUN fields.

However, I've seen [examples of people using it](http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html) in `ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}`. It doesn't work for me, apparently.

How can I pass the serial number of my device to the systemd template?

---

EDIT: I've also tried [this](http://blog.fraggod.net/2015/01/12/starting-systemd-service-instance-for-device-from-udev.html), but nope:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1366", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1015", ATTRS{serial}=="000621000000", SYMLINK+="ttymkw", PROGRAM="/bin/systemd-escape -p --template=offnet-uart-log@.service $env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="%c"
```

Comment: If your systemd service starts a script, you could call `udevadm info` inside your script and use `grep` to extract the `ID_SERIAL_SHORT`. Would that be an option or are there other boundary conditions which prevent this approach?

Comment: @AdminBee This is a possible work-around, thanks. At the same time, it feels like there should be an actual solution. Seeing people using `$env{ID_SERIAL}` in their solutions frustrates me.

Comment: Yes, I can very much relate to that ... If you agree, I will also post it as a regular solution, although you are of course right in that it is only a workaround.

Comment: TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}+="<unit>" is triggered only *once per boot* or something like that. man systemd.device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter I am looking for is `$attr{serial}`. I'm not sure why other solutions didn't work when it worked for others, I guess they are obsolete (EDIT: it's probably because my rule file, starting with 10-, is read before the rule file that creates the environment variable ID_SERIAL, starting with 60-). This is working:

udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1366", SYMLINK+="ttymkw", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="offnet-uart-log@$attr{serial}"
```

Systemd template:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start log of UART for a Offnet unit

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/bin/echo %i >> /tmp/asdf.log"
```

Apparently I don't need the `TAG`, and I need to use `$attr` instead of `$env`.

systemd version is 241.

The [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071589/execution-of-udevs-run-statement-after-systemctl-start-of-service) that helped me.

---

EDIT: a reason for `$env` not working could be that `ID_SERIAL_SHORT` is created on a rule on level 60, while my file is `10-local.rules`. [Thanks](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/14009#issuecomment-553359824) @yuwata. (Not verified.)

Answer (score 1):

As another workaround, if the *systemd* service is calling a script in its *ExecStart* statement, the same `udevadm` call shown in the question could be included in that script to extract the `ID_SERIAL_SHORT` via `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I can create my own environment variable in the udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1366", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1015", \
ATTRS{serial}=="000621000000", SYMLINK+="ttymkw", TAG+="systemd", \ 
ENV{MY_ID}="000621000000", \
ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}+="offnet-uart-log@$env{MY_ID}.service"
```

(backslashes for readability, this should be on a single line.)

Or really, just write the string directly after `@`.

These should not be needed though.